# getting date and time in c

Tags: c, string, date, time

I need to get the date as one string and the current time as another in C. I've had a look at time.h and see it allows me to get the whole thing. Do I then have to use some string methods? I notice that C doesn't have a substring method? Strcpy seems like it might work but I need a char * not an array.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `strftime` for this:

```
struct tm *tm;
time_t t;
char str_time[100];
char str_date[100];

t = time(NULL);
tm = localtime(&t);

strftime(str_time, sizeof(str_time), "%H %M %S", tm);
strftime(str_date, sizeof(str_date), "%d %m %Y", tm);
```

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I try to run this? I'm pretty new to C, do I have to malloc tm?

Comment: @drunkmonkey Yeah, I forgot `localtime` expects a `time_t *`. I edited the answer. Your compiler should have warned you though.

Comment: Try a variable of type time_t rather than NULL

Comment: @noMAD Well `time` is supposed to accept a `NULL`. The problem was it returns a `time_t` and `localtime` wants a `time_t *`.