# Timestamp of current time

Tags: c

For an application I'm building I need the timestamp of current time. How can I get the timestamp of current time in C?

Comment: Have you even tried google before asking here?

Comment: This is a really basic question. I just searched Google and got 4 answers on the first page, and the second result on this site was completely relevant. Try searching around a little first. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233123/getting-date-and-time-in-c) a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) link.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Simplified version to get the system time, not the local time.

```
time_t now = time(0);
```